# (Reopened) Why is the "tactics for rewarding employees" question considered "Opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion

Why did folks vote to close this question as "opinion-based"?

[Tactics for rewarding employees - keep them motivated and eager for work - long term employee retention](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/153890/tactics-for-rewarding-employees-keep-them-motivated-and-eager-for-work-long)

It's certainly no more opinion-based than the average question here.

Is it because the question is more oriented to management?

Anyway, I voted to re-open the question, and I encourage others to help.

Comment: It's apparently again attracting close votes. I already voted to reopen the first time it was closed so I can't again. May have to edit the title of this later on.

Comment: Asking for a list of tactics (or a list of anything else) would be too broad, and the question is definitely sprinkled with a bit too much "tell me your personal experience" and invites discussion as opposed to asking an concrete question. But underlying question of how to keep employees motivated is probably fine. It's sad that barely any of the answerers or close- or reopen voters bother making significant edits to questions. And yes, I put "answerers" first for a reason: they should be the most motivated to make sure the question they're answering is the best it can be.

Comment: @Dukeling - to be fair, answerers likely think the question is good enough to provide an answer. Seems like they would be less likely to see a reason to improve it.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Posting an answer comes with an implied endorsement of the question. I wouldn't endorse something that's not of decent quality. And I want my answers to be as useful as possible to as many people as possible. Making my answer as general as possible without sacrificing the specificity required to help OP is one way to do this, but making an overly-specific question I answer more general makes it much easier to find for others with a similar problem and makes it seem like it better matches their problem. But of course I don't expect everyone to share my way of thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Didn't vote to close; Didn't vote to reopen.

I'm thinking that what makes it more opinion-based on average is that "motivation" differ from a person to another, and what one may find motivational is another one's reason to leave.

Defining motivation can be a difficult subject either.

I suspect an objective answer to this would be very vague. It's more a call to people's experiences than a solvable problem.

I would happily participate in this but I would doubt this would bring anything really new to a simple "it depends".

EDIT : In the end I gave the final vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

I've voted to reopen as well. I think "opinion based" gets over-used as a close reason. My interpretation is that it's intended for *purely* opinion based questions (i.e. what's your favorite color?) and not questions where an "opinion" can otherwise be a legitimate answer - you can back it up, you can explain the reasons why different opinions may exist and what to do about them, and so on.

In other words, there's no point in asking what someone's favorite color is, because there are infinite answers, there's no way to defend any specific answer, and one person's answer has no value to anyone else. That's opinion based, and should be closed.

But this question is answerable, and even in the sense that there will be different "opinions" about what motivates employees, it's fairly straightforward to iterate them and back them up in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Voted to close earlier (vote #3, I believe):

**Reason to close**: If I recall correctly, it asks for individual's past experience, meaning it will likely solicit a lot of low quality answers. A lot of "one time, this happened. that was nice" type answers. I think if the answer can't be answered in one post, it's probably too vague/broad.

**Reason for opinion-based**: I think it needs more focus, but I vaguely recall clicking opinion-based, simply because that's what the other two before me voted....whoops.

I still don't think it should be reopened, and it already has (at this point), 3 more close votes (which brings it to what, 8 now?)

Edit: Oops, I was one of the second round voters, and apparently I properly voted for Needs More Focus, so I guess you can ignore this

Answer (score -1):

**I voted to close because the question is too broad.** There is no specific, detailed problem to be solved, or professional situation to navigate.

"How to keep employees motivated and eager for work" seems like a topic for a two-semester course in MBA school or something.

> It's certainly no more opinion-based than the average question here.

I don't know how we can measure that, assuming we want the metric of "subjectivity" to go somewhere. I consider every question separately, looking mostly for

> [clear goal we can address](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The question does seem to have a clear goal though: *keep employees motivated.* Personally, I don't think "too broad" should apply unless a question is broad to the point that it is literally unanswerable. And the presence of several highly voted answers on this question seems to think that a very large number of people consider this question answerable. I think it would be a disservice to close it (again).